# Is markup formatting just for Swift playgrounds?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In swift file, I don’t see editor _ show rendered markup button.

For example.

```
//: - Experiment:
//: Modify the `anyCommonElements(_:_:)` function to make a function that returns an array of the elements that any two sequences have in common.
//:
```

How can I show this in rendered markup mode in swift file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup formatting is exclusive for playgrounds and Quick Help. In other words, it's not possible to render the markup in a swift file in your Xcode project, but you can use it to improve the documentation that is displayed in Quick Help. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1), and [this](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-markdown/) for more info.

---

**Update (2021-11-05):** Starting on Xcode 13, there's a framework named [DocC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/docc) which brings new features for documentation using markup language.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. There is no show rendered markup in .swift file.

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit, just to be clearer about what I meant by "exclusive". Is this ok?

Comment: Yeah it is clear. Can’t show rendered format but we can use for quick help in swift file.

Comment: @user28434 thanks. I just wonder how I use it in swift file. I continue to do simple commenting.